# Relationship between voltage amplitude and dissipated heat for current running across a resistor

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, dissipation

I'm trying to figure out how *voltage amplitude* and *dissipated heat* relate for current running across a resistor at some arbitrarily very high frequency. The numbers used are less important that the math and logic behind them.

For example, say I have a $10k$ resistor and want $1$ Watt of heat to dissipate for a $1000$ Hz frequency. What voltage amplitude am I going to need for the voltage entering the resistor? (Again, numbers aren't really important. I just picked multiples of 10 for arbitrary convenience.)

I know the heat dissipated across the resistor is simply the power dissipated. I know (time-average) power for some current $Ie^{iwt}$ and voltage $Ve^{iwt}$ is just $$<W> = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Re}(IV)$$

Not entirely sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

for low frequencies (up to some kHz in most cases) you can ignore it. This means, it does not matter if your AS is a 50Hz or 1000Hz. At higher frequencies you start to get influences by the inductivity of the resistor and wires and capacitive loading.
For the sake of this we'll ignore that.

So
$$
P = U^2 / R
$$
where U is the RMS-Value of the voltage applied.

For sinusodidial voltages, RMS is $Vrms = Vpeak /\sqrt{2}$